# Depressed before even finding work

Tags: job-search, depression

I worked in an Indian auditing firm as article assistant. I had a decent exposure. I never doubted my abilities until I started working. I slowly learned that I lack analytical ability coupled with the fact that I kept making too many silly mistakes. Naturally I lost opportunities to work in better projects. As a result my self esteem took a hit.

I appeared for my final exams and failed pretty badly. I tried to work very hard but again failed with no improvement.  I lost all my confidence. 
I find that I have become incredibly dull. I started searching for a job. But my attitude remains the same. I am finding it difficult to grasp any information as my mind is restless.

I just hope I am not alone. I wish someone will give a better perspective as to how to move on. I want to live a normal healthy life. Can anyone share some light?

Comment: Share some light on what? Anyway, it appears like your situation is more on how to deal with yourself than a particular workplace situation. This may not be the right forum for this.

Comment: Welcome to life. YOu know all the things about being nice to you, safe spaces, the world being fair, you deserving an opportunity? Those are lies told at universities. The world is a harsh unfair place where you have to either fight for your fortune, or will forever be at the call of others. There are 3 types of people. hose who make things happen, those who watch things happen, and those who wonder what happened.. Quote from MAry Kay ash. Time to get your job together or move on - to something you can handle. This happens when you push people through an education without actually challenging.

Comment: *"I appeared for my Final exams and failed pretty badly."* - Are you saying you took a test at work? Or did you mean you failed school? It's unclear why you're looking for a new job or if you were fired from the current job.

Comment: That sounds like a tough situation to be in, but unfortunately your question is not one we can answer here. Take a look at our [tour] and [help] to get a feel for what kinds of questions we allow here. Really your situation sounds like something you should be talking to a counselor or therapist, or friends and family willing to lend an ear.

Comment: Everyone will get smacked down frequently by life. The secret is to pick yourself up and fix what you did wrong and try again.

Answer (score 5):

This might not be the correct forum for this, but maybe my own story can help you a little:

I have found myself in a similar situation a couple of years ago and I must admit it was tough. Not only the fact that I was without a job and worrying about the future, but also that my entire self image was shattered. I had always put all my self esteem in my studies and work and when I didn't have that anymore, I felt worthless.

However, it will definitely get better. The most important factor for me was actually getting a new job and seeing that I was actually capable of accomplishing stuff there. The old job was not for me, too much freedom and too much responsibility. The new job had less freedom and more structure and that worked better for me.

Another factor that has helped a lot was to talk about it with (in my case) both my mother and a therapist. And finding ways to redefine the value of yourself in a way that was less reliant on performance and more on other aspects of life.

I still struggle with anxiety and doubting my self periodically, but I can also see the things I have actually accomplished since then and am actively working on focusing on the good rather than the bad, but it is as you probably now easier said than done.

**TLDR: Don't let this failure define you, and don't get too afraid of failing again that you don't search out new opportunities. Try to see a new job opportunity as a possibility to redeem your self, rather than as a new job to fail at. These things is easy to say, but hard to do. Try to work on it with a therapist or a person you trust.**

I wish you the best of luck in the future, and hope everything works out.